# get_posts only children from certain parents

Tags: get-posts

I have parent posts (custom post type hierarch=true) with ID 1, 2, 3, 4.

The parent posts with ID 2 and 4 have child pages.

I need to retrieve only posts 2 and 4 and all of their child pages.

Something like this

```
$argsch = array('orderby' => 'date','order' => 'DESC','post_type' => 'products', 'include' => '2, 4');
$childs = get_posts($argsch);
```

How can I edit this to return child pages of the included id's?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Call get_posts multiple times: one for the parent pages using `post__in => array(2,4)`, and two for the child pages of each parent with `post_parent => 2` and `post_parent => 4` and finally merge all the results into a single array.
2. Write directly your SQL query and use `$wpdb->get_results`. See  [this article](http://www.devdevote.com/cms/wordpress-hacks/use-sql-querys-in-the-loop-with-template-tags/) for an example. In your case it would be something similar to the following (not tested) code:

   ```
   $query_sql = "
       SELECT *
       FROM $wpdb->posts
       WHERE post_type = 'products'
       AND (ID IN (2,4) OR post_parent IN (2,4))
       ORDER BY post_date DESC
   ";
   $query_result = $wpdb->get_results($query_sql, OBJECT);
   ```

Comment: the first on is bad, becouse I dont know exact count of Ids there might be.  The second on seem good to me. Ill try.

Answer (score 1):

```
$args = array('orderby' => 'date','order' => 'DESC','post_type' => 'products', 'include' => '2, 4');

// get the 2 and 4 posts
$children = get_posts($args);

// get the children of 2, and merge arrays
$children = array_merge($children,get_posts(array('orderby' => 'date','order' => 'DESC','post_type' => 'products','post_parent'=>2)));

// get the children of 4, and merge arrays
$children = array_merge($children,get_posts(array('orderby' => 'date','order' => 'DESC','post_type' => 'products','post_parent'=>4)));

foreach($children as $child){
    // etc
}
```

Although it would be much much easier/faster if you could tag them in a custom taxonomy or identify them some other way so that you were only needing to look for one thing, rather than 3 things.

e.g. if we had a custom taxonomy 'highlighted_products' we might do:

```
$children = get_posts('post_type' => 'products', 'orderby' => 'date','order' => 'DESC','highlighted_products' => 'example_page');
foreach($children as $child){
    // etc
}
```

Which would be far more flexible, less prone to errors ( ID 2 and 4 might change! Don't hardcode ), and it's a lot faster to do, no raw SQL or multiple queries. Not to mention that you now have a nice user friendly UI in the backend where you just tag a products post and it appears in the right place

Answer (score 1):

```
$children = get_posts('post_parent=SLUG_OF_PARENT_POST&post_status=publish');
foreach($children as $child)
{
echo '<br/>ID:'.$child->ID;
}
```

you can use other attributes (i.e. `$child->post_content`)...
if you need to define post_type, then add this argument too : `&post_type=POST_TYPE_NAME`