# wp query to get child pages of current page

Tags: wp-query, child-pages

Can anyone please help me to with the wp_query.

I am making a template file/loop to create and archive page of the current page children pages.

This query needs to be automatic as I am using in on few pages.

This is my query below, but it just returns my posts instead of child pages.

```
<?php

$parent = new WP_Query(array(

    'post_parent'       => $post->ID,                               
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'orderby'           => 'menu_order',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1

));

if ($parent->have_posts()) : ?>

    <?php while ($parent->have_posts()) : $parent->the_post(); ?>

        <div id="parent-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="parent-page">                                

            <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

            <p><?php the_advanced_excerpt(); ?></p>

        </div>  

    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php unset($parent); endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Josh

Comment: Try this solution
==
get children of a post - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/123143/42702

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You have to change `child_of` to `post_parent` and also add `post_type => 'page'`:

WordPress codex Wp_query [Post & Page Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters)

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order'
 );


$parent = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $parent->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php while ( $parent->have_posts() ) : $parent->the_post(); ?>

        <div id="parent-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="parent-page">

            <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

            <p><?php the_advanced_excerpt(); ?></p>

        </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks dude, I tried `post_parent` original but it's  `'post_type' => 'page'` that is the key - does wordpress querys default to post then? I will accept answer when it lets me.

Comment: Yes, `'post_type' => 'post'` is default.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is a very old question, but since I landed on it, others might as well.

Wordpress has a very simple solution for listing pages, where you can add some arguments as well.

This is all you will need to display a page's children:

```
wp_list_pages(array(
  'child_of' => $post->ID,
  'title_li' => ''
))
```

Look at the [reference page for wp_list_pages](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/) for all options you can apply.

Comment: This will return an HTML string rather than a list of post objects, so probably not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting this to a function in functions.php you need to add 
global $post;

```
function page_summary() {
    global $post;
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'page',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
        'order'          => 'ASC',
        'orderby'        => 'menu_order'
    );


    $parent = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $parent->have_posts() ) : 

        while ( $parent->have_posts() ) : $parent->the_post(); ?>
        <div id="parent-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="parent-page">

        <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
        </div>
    <?php
         endwhile; 

    endif; 
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Though OP asked specifically for a `wp_query`, this also works: 
`get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID.'&sort_column=menu_order');`